# How to link to images without Rails helpers in deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Rails 4 app. HTML for it is already built, so I would like to use tags that I already have (everything works locally). But when I deploy my app to Heroku, none of the images are displayed.

Example of my current image tag:

```
<img src="/assets/blog/post_images/1.png">
```

How should I change it so that Heroku knows where to look (I've tried many!)?
Or what are the proper steps to 'precomplile' images? This is the solution I use now:

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

It does work (all images are displayed), but I heard that it makes app in production slower.

**EDIT**
CSS and Javascript files are found just fine interestingly. I thought maybe it has something to do with this file (*config/initializers/assets.rb*):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( blog_posts.css )
```

These are my contents. Should this file mention images may be?

Comment: Type this command in your root application directory, rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: @RubyOnRails, I've tried it, public folder with insides appeared, I commited it to Heroku, but images are still not displayed.

Comment: Can you check all css, js, images are inside public/assets folder!!!!

Comment: @RubyOnRails, I added some more information.

Comment: How many you have css files, are you calling this image <img src="/assets/blog/post_images/1.png"> directly or it's inside css file.